# intensity at same point

Tags: waves, interference

I was reading a book . In which there is a solved question . As given below . [image]

My doubt in question is that how they have written I=4I'  ?

Comment: What I need to do to get it reopened

Answer (score 1):

The intensity of the wave is proportional to the square of the amplitude. In the center amplitude is doubled (A+A=2A), so intensity is quadrupled.

Comment: How do we know at centre amplitude is double

Comment: The amplitude is a vector and they point in the same direction. Hence, they double.